# Only allow approved USB devices to connect to device

Tags: windows

I'm working for a client who has built a Medical product that is built on top of Windows 10. The application logs have to be manually extracted via USB, however the client only wants specific, preauthorized USBs to be allowed to attach.

Is there a native Windows or Eset solution for this?

I've seen that Microsoft Defender for Endpoint and Endpoint Manager as well as ATP have this capability but nothing else.

Comment: I had a friend mention this to me: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/925a8053-027c-4c7b-9b02-8d91d83bf74a/group-policy-allowing-certain-usb-stick-but-deny-all-other-usb-devices?forum=winserverGP

Comment: I'm not sure we can comment on what Eset offers. That will be a call in to them.

Comment: Yes, Group Policy can achieve part of what you want and Defender. If you have these in hand, what are you asking for, exactly? I'm starting to wonder if this question should be moved to ServerFault if you want to know how to configure GP or Defender.

Comment: @shroeder. Thank you. I looked into how to configure this properly. I belive I figured it out using Group Policy.